# How to delete "1" followed by trailing zeros from Data Frame row values ?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

From my "Id" Column I want to remove the one and zero's from the left.
That is 
1000003 becomes 3
1000005 becomes 5
1000011 becomes 11 and so on

Ignore -1, 10 and 1000000, they will be handled as special cases. but from the remaining rows I want to remove the "1" followed by zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use modulus to get the end of the numbers (they will be the remainder). So just exclude the rows with ids of [-1,10,1000000] and then compute the modulus of 1000000:

```py
print df

        Id
0       -1
1       10
2  1000000
3  1000003
4  1000005
5  1000007
6  1000009
7  1000011

keep = df.Id.isin([-1,10,1000000])
df.Id[~keep] = df.Id[~keep] % 1000000
print df

        Id
0       -1
1       10
2  1000000
3        3
4        5
5        7
6        9
7       11
```

**Edit:** Here is a fully vectorized string slice version as an alternative (Like Alex' method but takes advantage of pandas' vectorized string methods):

```py
keep = df.Id.isin([-1,10,1000000])
df.Id[~keep] = df.Id[~keep].astype(str).str[1:].astype(int)
print df

        Id
0       -1
1       10
2  1000000
3        3
4        5
5        7
6        9
7       11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could try to do it:

```
def f(x):
    """convert the value to a string, then select only the characters
       after the first one in the string, which is 1. For example,
       100005 would be 00005 and I believe it's returning 00005.0 from 
       dataframe, which is why the float() is there. Then just convert 
       it to an int, and you'll have 5, etc.
    """
    return int(float(str(x)[1:]))

# apply the function "f" to the dataframe and pass in the column 'Id'
df.apply(lambda row: f(row['Id']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I get that this question is satisfactory answered. But for future visitors, what I like about alex' answer is that it does not depend on there to be exactly four zeros. The accepted answer will fail if you sometimes have `10005`, sometimes `1000005` and whatever.

However, to add something more to the way we think about it. If you *know* it's always going to be 10000, you can do

```
# backup all values
foo = df.id 
#now, some will be negative or zero
df.id = df.id - 10000 
#back in those that are negative or zero (here, first three rows)
df.if[df.if <= 0] = foo[df.id <= 0]
```

It gives you the same as Karl's answer, but I typically prefer these kind of methods for their readability.

Comment: By the way, does anyone know why syntax highlighting doesnt work in this post?